# cinder not creating volume

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-cinder

I am exploring devstack and i am getting a weird error.
I only have 2 instances (with volume) so far. Both are currently 5GB in size. When I try to create any more instance with volume I get "error".
I have checked the limits for the number of volumes and it is 10 and there are only 2 volumes so far.

I tried both the devstack UI and the command line but both are failing.

The following is the command line that failed:

```
cinder create --display-name test 2
```

I forgot to add the log for cinder in the initial setup.However, I have turned the verbose, and debug on in /etc/cinder/cinder.conf

```
verbose = True
debug = True
```

Can I get help in identifying the reason I cannot create more volumes and also how to go about getting the log for cinder?

I got following error from the cinder-scheduler

```
Insufficient free space for volume creation (requested / avail): 1/0.0
```

I looked at this more closely. The lvm-driver volume is limited to 10GB. When I do: sudo vgdisplay I see this limit.
I am guessing this is configured at the very beginning when I run stack.sh. My question is how do I increase this size?

Answer (score 4):

The devstack default is 10GB, as you say. This size is affected by the following configuration variable:

```
VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE=10250M
```

If you don't have this in your configuration, then add it and set it to a bigger number. For more details, see the Cinder section in the [configuration help page](http://devstack.org/configuration.html).

Answer (score -1):

Resize the volume by passing the volume ID and the new size (a value greater than the old one) as parameters:

**

> $ cinder extend 573e024d-5235-49ce-8332-be1576d323f8 10

**